# Can't wrap my head around Browser caching and gzip/deflate in .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, gzip, browser-cache, deflate

I've added those lines to my `.htaccess`-file. And yes, I understand what they should do and how they should work. I don't get any internal server errors, but *Google PageSpeed Insights* still says, that I need to turn on Browser Caching and that I should deflate/gzip my files. What's not working here?

Even in case let's say `mod_filter` or `mod_deflate` aren't available the cache control should work at least, right?

`.htaccess`-file:

```
# cache control
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</filesMatch>

# gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>

# deflate
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
        "application/javascript" \
        "application/json" \
        "application/ld+json" \
        "application/manifest+json" \
        "application/rdf+xml" \
        "application/rss+xml" \
        "application/schema+json" \
        "application/vnd.geo+json" \
        "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
        "application/x-font-ttf" \
        "application/x-javascript" \
        "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
        "application/xhtml+xml" \
        "application/xml" \
        "font/eot" \
        "font/opentype" \
        "image/bmp" \
        "image/svg+xml" \
        "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
        "image/x-icon" \
        "text/cache-manifest" \
        "text/css" \
        "text/html" \
        "text/javascript" \
        "text/plain" \
        "text/vcard" \
        "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
        "text/vtt" \
        "text/x-component" \
        "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
        "text/xml"
</IfModule>
```

Other parts, like `mod_rewrite` are working like a charme. So the `.htaccess`is definetely taken into account. Maybe I'm just missing something here.

Comment: Are any file types being deflated? Better to check this using the network section of a browser debugger rather than google pageinsights. You can check each component of your page (css, js, html, etc...) individually to see if any have the correct `Content-encoding: gzip` header.

Comment: I've checked it with Firebug and it seems to work – also Google PageSpeed Insights checks it now. Might have been a caching problem on their site. Thanks a lot for the tip. Funny though that PageSpeed Insights still says that the caching for analytics.js and Maps API should be improved. :D

Answer (score 0):

To enable caching use this:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```